# Wine installation failure

Tags: wine

I'm trying to install Wine on a computer running Ubuntu 16.10.  For some reason I'm unable to successfully install Wine on this computer.

Here are the limitations I'm up against.
I have to use Ubuntu 16.10 because of a network problem with Ubuntu 17.04.
Do to network restrictions, I am unable to run any commands through the terminal that involves a connection to the network.

I have tried running the install Wine through the software centre but it goes through the install process but I can't launch Wine.  I go back into the software centre to check to see if it is installed but it shows that it's not installed.

Can any one help me please.

Comment: How are you trying to "launch wine"? Cause you don't really do that.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to try to install Wine again but I used the command `sudo apt-get install wine-stable`. Something must have changed since I last tried to install Wine because it worked this time.

I now have wine successfully installed.

Thanks for your help.